# Array of strings as hash function key?

Tags: arrays, string, function, hash, key

Is it possible, in any language (it doesn't matter), to have a hash function which uses an array of strings as keys?

I mean something like this:

```
hash(["word1", "word2", ...]) = "element"
```

instead of the classical:

```
hash("word") = "element"
```

I need something like that because each word I would like to use as key could change the output element of the function. I've got a sequence of words and I want a specific output for that sequence (also the order may change the result).

Comment: you could concatenate the elements of the list and use the string-based function

Comment: Yes, but it is not advisable because arrays are mutable and mutable keys in hashes/dicts/maps can cause strange runtime errors.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar I don't think the problem would be mutability.  In Java as long as you can implement hashCode and equals your object should be key worthy.  So you could use an ArrayList as a key, as long as your hashCode/equals assures the results you expect.

Comment: @gebuh http://stackoverflow.com/q/7842049/126916

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar: I don't think Alex is asking about a Java hash, but for a hash that is a function of the values of the array. So, for example, if you had two arrays with the same elements, in the same order, their Java hash should be different, whereas the function Alex wants should not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Any data structure at all can be hashed.  You only need to come up with a strict definition of equality and then ensure that hash(A) == hash(B) if A == B.  Suppose your definition is that [s1, s2, ..., sm] == [t1, t2, ..., tn] if and only if  m == n and si == ti for i = 1..m and further string s == t if and only if |s|==|t| and s[i]==t[i] for 0<=i<|s|. You can build a hash in a many, many ways:

- Concatenate all the strings in the list and hash the result with any string hash function.
- Do the same, adding separators such as commas (,)
- Hash each string individually and xor the results.
- Hash eash string individually, shift the previous hash value, and xor the new value into the hash.
- Infinitely many more possibilities...

Tigorous definition of equality is important. If for example order doesn't matter in the lists or the string comparison is case-insensitive, then the hash function must still be designed to ensure hash(A) == hash(B) if A == B .  Getting this wrong will cause lookups to fail.

Java is one language that lets you define a hash function for any data type.  And in fact a library list of strings will work just fine as a key using the default hash function.

```
HashMap<ArrayList<String>, String> map = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, String>();

ArrayList<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();
key.add("Hello");
key.add("World");

map.put(key, "It's me.");
// map now contains mapping ["Hello", "World"] -> "It's me."
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but in most cases you will have to define your own hash function that translates an array into a hash-key. For example, in java, the array.hashCode() is based on the Object.hashCode() function which is based on the Reference itself and not the contents of the Object.

You may also have a look at [Arrays.deepHashCode() function in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) if you are interested in an implementation of a hashing function built on top of an array.

Comment: The other answer was better explained, but I want to thank you too! Your link would be very helpful!