# Mmutable objects in hash collections in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, immutability, hashcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are mutable hashmap keys a dangerous practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice)

What happens if muttable objects in hashtable are modified without using any of the hashmap APIs

Does the object in hashmap change ? .
Does it get lost since its value has changed ?

How does it exactly work ?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this question should cover it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7941876/364206

Comment: Assuming you're talking about using mutable objects for the key in the map, then this duplicate question is what you're looking for. If you're talking about using them as the value, then you have nothing to worry about.