# HashMap put does not add value for Points with one dimension over 128, no overflow error

Tags: java, hashmap

I defined a class Point that represents a point on an integer lattice.  I have overridden methods for hashCode() and equals(Object).

HashMap does not seem to do anything when using HashMap.put(Point, Double) for Points with a coordinate value >= 128.  No error is thrown, but attempting to access Points from the HashMap will result in the key not being found.  I am well under INTEGER.MAX_VALUE, and have plenty of memory available.

Here is my Point class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Point {
    protected int dimension;
    protected ArrayList<Integer> coordinates;

    public Point(int[] coordinates){
        this.coordinates = convertArray(coordinates);
        dimension = coordinates.length;
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> convertArray(int[] array){
        ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            newArray.add(array[i]);
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        // Some arbitrary quick hash
        return coordinates.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        Point p = (Point)o;
        if(dimension != p.coordinates.size())
            return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < p.coordinates.size(); i++){
            if(coordinates.get(i) != p.coordinates.get(i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the test I ran:

```
import java.util.*;
public class random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Point, Double> weight = new HashMap<Point, Double>((int)(150 * 150 * .75 + 1));
        for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 150; j++){
                int [] tmpArray = {i, j};
                weight.put(new Point(tmpArray), Math.random());
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 150; j++){
                int [] tmpArray = {i, j};
                if(weight.get(new Point(tmpArray)) == null){
                    System.out.println("[" + i + ", " + j + "]: ");
                    System.out.println(weight.containsKey(new Point(tmpArray)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        Point p = (Point)o;
        if(dimension != p.coordinates.size())
            return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < p.coordinates.size(); i++){
            if(coordinates.get(i) != p.coordinates.get(i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Your `equals()` implementation is bad when you compare objects you must use `equals` to observational equality instead of `==` that is if they point to same location (!=).

`Integer` is an object so you have to use `equals` .Sometimes doing `==` works fine to same values cause they are cached ( -128 to 127).

Example:

```
Integer a = 1000, b = 1000;  
System.out.println(a == b); // false  
Integer c = 100, d = 100;  
System.out.println(c == d); // true
Integer e=5 , f= new Integer(5);
System.out.println(e == f) // false
```

Instead of looping your list you can simply use provided list method  [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both
>   lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
>   the two lists are equal

Also you shouldn't use as `Key` in `hash valued map` mutable objects.  [Are mutable hashmap key dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice)

> If an object’s hashCode() value can change based on its state, then we
>   must be careful when using such objects as keys in hash-based
>   collections to ensure that we don’t allow their state to change when
>   they are being used as hash keys. All hash-based collections assume
>   that an object’s hash value does not change while it is in use as a
>   key in the collection. If a key’s hash code were to change while it
>   was in a collection, some unpredictable and confusing consequences
>   could follow.