# Issues when extending AbstractStringBuilder and using the subclass in a Hashtable

Tags: java, inheritance, hashtable, super

I want to extend AbstractStringBuilder and get a class same to StringBuilder but having a hashCode() method identical to String.hashCode(). The intention is to use this new subclass as a key in a Hashtable. I want to experiment with Hashtable and this new subclass and see what happens, because in the end I want to solve some memory issues which StringBuilder solves some of them but not all of them. So,here is the subclass,

```
import java.lang.*;

public final class StringCon extends AbstractStringBuilder implements java.io.Serializable, CharSequence
{
    public StringCon()
    {
        super( 16);
    }

    public StringCon( int capacity)
    {
        super( capacity);
    }

    public StringCon( String str)
    {
        super( str.length() + 16);
        append( str);
    }

    public StringCon append( Object obj)
    {
        return append( String.valueOf( obj));
    }

    public StringCon append( String str)
    {
        super.append( str);
        return this;
    }

    public StringCon delete( int start, int end)
    {
        super.delete( start, end);
        return this;
    }

    public StringCon delete( int start)
    {
        super.delete( start, this.length());
        return this;
    }

    public int indexOf( String str)
    {
        return indexOf( str, 0);
    }

    public int indexOf( String str, int fromIndex)
    {
        return String.indexOf( value, 0, count, str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length(), fromIndex);
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        int h = hash;
        if( h == 0 && count > 0)
        {
            int off = 0;
            char val[] = value;
            int len = count;
            for( int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                h = 31*h + val[ off++];

            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
}
```

I implement only the methods that I am going to use. The questions are,

1) Compiler doesn't find symbols value, count and even the keyword super. These symbols are defined in AbstarctStringBuilder and StringBuilder uses them freely. Why?

2) Compiler cannot find method AbstractStringBuilder.substring(). Why?

3) I get the error,

```
error: type argument StringCon is not within bounds of type-variable E
```

in a statement

```
hth = ( j + 1 < al.size()) ? new Hashtable< StringCon, LinkedList< StringCon>>( al.get( j + 1).size(), 0.75F) : null;
```

4) I get the error

```
error: method containsKey in class Hashtable<K,V> cannot be applied to given types;
                    if( hth.isEmpty() || !hth.containsKey( nextKey))
                                             ^
required: Object
found: StringCon
reason: actual argument StringCon cannot be converted to Object by method invocation conversion
where K,V are type-variables:
 K extends Object declared in class Hashtable
 V extends Object declared in class Hashtable
```

where nextKey is a StringCon object.

The various methods above I have copied them from StringBuilder and String classes.

What is it that I don't understand, where are my mistakes? I am using all the above in the context of Hadoop, if this has any importance.

Comment: What is the full type of `hth`?

Comment: Please show the line where the `hth` variable/field is first declared.

Comment: Straight from the code, Hashtable< StringCon, LinkedList< StringCon>> hth = null; hth = new Hashtable< StringCon, LinkedList< StringCon>>( someSize, 0.75F); where the someSize changes from iteration to iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder` is not `public`, so it can only be extended by other classes in `java.lang`. Trying to compile your code gives the first error:

```
StringCon.java:3: java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder is not public in java.lang;
cannot be accessed from outside package
```

Using a mutable class as a key in a hashtable is not generally advisable ([Are mutable hashmap keys a dangerous practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice)). There may be a better way to solve your problem:

> because in the end I want to solve some memory issues which StringBuilder solves some of them but not all of them

Consider asking a direct question about the memory issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I considered of asking directly about the memory issues, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949658/memory-problems-with-java-in-the-context-of-hadoop :) Your answer was also a good lesson of looking the whole compiler output at first and not a part of it.