# Updating mapped values for a TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>>

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I am reading in a file like:

```
Tom Boyscouts Red_Cross
Jim Boyscouts FLBA
Jerry FBLA Red_Cross


    while (file.ready()) {
        ArrayList<String> nameToOrg= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(file.readLine().split(" ")));
        String members = list.remove(0);

        for (String key : nameToOrg) {
            if (treemap.get(key) == null) {
                TreeSet<String> membersAdded = new TreeSet<String>();   //Declare new TreeSet
                membersAdded.add(members);                              //Add this member
                treemap.put(key, membersAdded);                         //put(key,TreeSet)
            }else{
                //.get the existing set of members

                //add this new member

                //.put back into map
            }   
        }
    }

    file.close();
```

The current output would be...

```
Boyscouts = [Jim]
FBLA = [Jerry]
Red_Cross = [Jerry]
```

The output I want would be

```
Boyscouts = [Jim, Tom]
FBLA = [Jerry, Jim]
Red_Cross = [Jerry, Tom]
```

I am mostly being tripped up by else statement in my for loop. My professor gave us the pseudo-code, but I am not exactly sure how to .get the existing set of members from a TreeSet, and then update it.

EDIT:
Thanks! Both of you had great answers, and really helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Map.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) and [Map.put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) methods.

A note about this process : you may ask "why the hell do I need to reinsert the item"? Isn't it enough to just update it? Well, unfortunately not, because the map doesn't know about the change.

Let's say we've got a binary search tree (say, a TreeMap in Java) :

```
                   2
                1     3
```

If you update the record with 1 to 4, the map won't notice the change and you'll end up with an invalid BST :

```
                   2
                4     3
```

Now, an odd situation might happen that `bst.contains(4)` returns `false` while `bst.keySet().contains(4)` returns `true`.

For more details, you can see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice).

In this case, it shouldn't be needed though because the keys (`String`s) are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

If key is already exist in map, still some code is missing in else part. like.
Get list from map and add `member`, i.e.

```
 treemap.get(key).add(members);
```

Try it

```
 for (String key : nameToOrg) {
            if (treemap.get(key) == null) {
             TreeSet<String> membersAdded = new TreeSet<String>();   //Declare new TreeSet
             membersAdded.add(members);                              //Add this member
              treemap.put(key, membersAdded);                         //put(key,TreeSet)
            }else{
               treemap.get(key).add(members);//write here code
            }   
        }
```

Comment: I've tried doing this before, but this just ends up adding every name to every organization. Like Boyscouts = [Jim, Jerry, Tom] , Red_Cross = [Jim, Jerry, Tom] , etc