# What is the hashCode of an AtomicBoolean?

Tags: java, hashcode, atomicboolean

I couldn't find any information in the official docs. I know that `Boolean.hashCode(boolean b)` returns the two primes 1231 and 1237 for true and false. I am hoping for a similar implementation in `AtomicBoolean`. But in the decompiled class file it appears to call `public native int hashCode();` of `Object` - does that mean it will return the memory location?

Comment: You could simply try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) tells why `hashCode` is not overriden for `AtomicBoolean`:

> Atomic classes are not general purpose replacements for java.lang.Integer and related classes. They do not define methods such as `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo`. (Because atomic variables are expected to be mutated, they are poor choices for hash table keys.)

***does that mean it will return the memory location?***

It depends on what JVM you use, but yes, it's usually derived from the memory address. Other JVMs may just use a random number.

Answer (score 2):

AtomicBoolean doesn't override hashCode (or equals), so it inherits the default Object behavior.

This actually makes a lot of sense. The main use case of hashCode is to let the object be the key of a hash map, but it's [dangerous to mutate keys once they're in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice). Since the main attribute of an AtomicBoolean *is* its mutability, this makes it a bad candidate for a HashMap key.

In other words: If you need it to be a HashMap key, you shouldn't mutate it, and if you don't intend to mutate it, then you shouldn't use an AtomicBoolean.

Answer (score 1):

`AtomicBoolean` does not override the `hashCode()` (or `equals(Object)`, for that matter) method. It uses the default implementation from `java.lang.Object`. Although it's not specified by the JLS, this implementation usually just returns the internal address of the object represented as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean uses hashode of object method , which is not overridden in the class.so it uses defult hascode of object class.