# Using a HashMap as a Key for another HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a requirement where I need to map a set of configurations with a set of values, ideally denoted by a `Map<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>` structure.

Both the configurations & the values part of the main Map are arbitrary & hence, I am unable to use a concrete class.

Please provide some feedback on this structure. Can a Map be used as a key for another Map. Doing a bit of research, I was able to establish that the Map's equals method utilizes all underlying Keys & Values to deem two Maps as equal. Also, the HashCode of a Map is based on the Hashcodes of the Map's Keys. This IMO should suffice the minimum requirements of using a Map as a key.

I would still like someone to validate this before I go ahead with the implementation. In case there is a better solution / design that someone can suggest, please feel free to do so.

**EDIT**

I ended up using a simple tilde ('~') & pipe ('|') separated String as the key & deconstructed it whenever needed. Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: You do not have that requirement. You only think you do.

Comment: You could probably somehow hack it together, but I think you should step back and be 100% certain that you can not use a String or a Pojo as the key.

Comment: Composing maps of maps is a clue that you should create some separate classes.

Comment: "*I ended up using a simple tilde ('~') & pipe ('|') separated String*" stringly-typed keys make me sad :'( - if you have structured data, use a structured type (i.e. a dedicated key type), don't mangle that structure into a string. [`@AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) makes it very easy to quickly define such types.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, a `HashMap` *can* be used as a key to another map, as the class properly overrides [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#hashCode--).

However it's broadly speaking a [bad idea to use mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7842049/113632) (such as `HashMap`) as `Map` keys or `Set` elements, because you violate the invariants these classes expect if the objects are mutated while in the collection.

While not quite what you're looking for, [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) offers several [additional data structures](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset) such as `Multiset`, `MultiMap`, `BiMap`, `Table` which may be useful. They also offer [immutable collections](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) such as `ImmutableMap` which (because they can't be mutated) are safer to use as a `Map` key. Which isn't to say you *should* do so, simply that it's safe (if the keys and values are also immutable).

Consider posting a question exploring the problem that lead you to conclude a `Map<Map<K, V>, Map<K, V>>` structure was what you needed. You may get better answers to *that* question.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I had completely overlooked immutability. Will look into immutable collections.

Comment: @Sumit, glad to help, but please also consider alternative data structures - nested maps are generally a code smell, and can quickly become difficult to work with.