# Java - unmodifiable key set map

Tags: java, dictionary, key, immutability

I am looking for a way to provide a `Map` with pre-defined (as in runtime immutable, not compile time const) constant key set, but modifiable values.

The JDK provides `Collections.unmodifiableMap` factory method, which wraps a `Map` and provides an immutable view of it.

Is there a similar way to wrap a `Map` so that only it's keys are immutable? For instance, `put(K,V)` will replace the value of existing keys, but throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if the key does not exist.

Comment: I would guess you could simply create your own class and override `put`. Check if the `key` exist, if not throw an `Exception`. Or creating some sort of Proxy to only provide some methods an hide the rest

Comment: @AxelH - That's a good idea, but one can still obtain the keySet and modify it directly. I need something more like `unmodifiableSet` as keySet, and `put` that does not touch the key if it already exists.

Comment: Why are your keys mutable in the first place? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice

Comment: The *keys* are immutable. The *key set* is mutable.

Comment: @Elist I have edited to prevent this, you can create a proxy class that will only provide the methods you want. So basicly the class will have an `Map` instance but will only provide the methods `put` and `get`

Comment: That's right @AxelH, but I was looking for an existing (peer reviewed) solution.

Comment: @Elist well you have a specific idea of what you want. You want a semi immutable map. So I wish you luck to find something existing. But I don't really see this as complicated as you think. But of course, it depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: @Elist I have updated my answer. If you don't find what you need there, I don't think I understood your problem ;)

Comment: Are the keys determined at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, all the solutions suggested here were to wrap or extend `Collections.UnmodifiableMap`. Both impossible since the original implementation would not allow to override `put` (and `replace` etc.), Which is exactly what makes it secure...

I see two options:

1. The "smelly" option - Using reflection to get hold of the original `Map<>` and directly call it's methods.
2. The "ugly" option - Copy the source of some of the static classes in `java.lang.Collections` and modify them.

If anyone has a better idea, please let me know.

---

Here is an initial implementation of the 2'nd solution:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import static java.util.Collections.unmodifiableCollection;
import static java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet;

/**
 * @serial include
 */
public class UnmodifiableKeySetMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Serializable {

    private final Map<K, V> m;

    /**
     * Returns a view of the specified map with unmodifiable key set. This 
     * method allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to 
     * internal maps. Query operations on the returned map "read through"
     * to the specified map, and attempts to modify the returned
     * map, whether direct or via its collection views, result in an
     * <tt>UnsupportedOperationException</tt>.<p>
     *
     * The returned map will be serializable if the specified map
     * is serializable.
     *
     * @param <K> the class of the map keys
     * @param <V> the class of the map values
     * @param  m the map for which an unmodifiable view is to be returned.
     * @return an unmodifiable view of the specified map.
     */
    public static <K,V> Map<K,V> unmodifiableKeySetMap(Map<K, V> m) {
        return new UnmodifiableKeySetMap<>(m);
    }

    UnmodifiableKeySetMap(Map<K, V> m) {
        if (m==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.m = m;
    }

    public int size()                        {return m.size();}
    public boolean isEmpty()                 {return m.isEmpty();}
    public boolean containsKey(Object key)   {return m.containsKey(key);}
    public boolean containsValue(Object val) {return m.containsValue(val);}
    public V get(Object key)                 {return m.get(key);}

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (containsKey(key)) {
            return m.put(key, value);
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public V remove(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private transient Set<K> keySet;
    private transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet;
    private transient Collection<V> values;

    public Set<K> keySet() {
        if (keySet==null)
            keySet = unmodifiableSet(m.keySet());
        return keySet;
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
        if (entrySet==null)
            entrySet = new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet<>(m.entrySet());
        return entrySet;
    }

    public Collection<V> values() {
        if (values==null)
            values = unmodifiableCollection(m.values());
        return values;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {return o == this || m.equals(o);}
    public int hashCode()           {return m.hashCode();}
    public String toString()        {return m.toString();}

    // Override default methods in Map
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public V getOrDefault(Object k, V defaultValue) {
        // Safe cast as we don't change the value
        return ((Map<K, V>)m).getOrDefault(k, defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
        m.forEach(action);
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceAll(BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> function) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object key, Object value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V computeIfPresent(K key,
                              BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V compute(K key,
                     BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V merge(K key, V value,
                   BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * @serial include
     */
    static class UnmodifiableSet<E> extends UnmodifiableCollection<E>
            implements Set<E>, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -9215047833775013803L;

        UnmodifiableSet(Set<? extends E> s)     {super(s);}
        public boolean equals(Object o) {return o == this || c.equals(o);}
        public int hashCode()           {return c.hashCode();}
    }

    /**
     * @serial include
     */
    static class UnmodifiableCollection<E> implements Collection<E>, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1820017752578914078L;

        final Collection<? extends E> c;

        UnmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
            if (c==null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            this.c = c;
        }

        public int size()                   {return c.size();}
        public boolean isEmpty()            {return c.isEmpty();}
        public boolean contains(Object o)   {return c.contains(o);}
        public Object[] toArray()           {return c.toArray();}
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)       {return c.toArray(a);}
        public String toString()            {return c.toString();}

        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<E>() {
                private final Iterator<? extends E> i = c.iterator();

                public boolean hasNext() {return i.hasNext();}
                public E next()          {return i.next();}
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
                @Override
                public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
                    // Use backing collection version
                    i.forEachRemaining(action);
                }
            };
        }

        public boolean add(E e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public boolean remove(Object o) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
            return c.containsAll(coll);
        }
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> coll) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> coll) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> coll) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public void clear() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        // Override default methods in Collection
        @Override
        public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
            c.forEach(action);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
            return (Spliterator<E>)c.spliterator();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Stream<E> stream() {
            return (Stream<E>)c.stream();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Stream<E> parallelStream() {
            return (Stream<E>)c.parallelStream();
        }
    }

    /**
     * We need this class in addition to UnmodifiableSet as
     * Map.Entries themselves permit modification of the backing Map
     * via their setValue operation.  This class is subtle: there are
     * many possible attacks that must be thwarted.
     *
     * @serial include
     */
    static class UnmodifiableEntrySet<K,V>
            extends UnmodifiableSet<Entry<K,V>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7854390611657943733L;

        @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
        UnmodifiableEntrySet(Set<? extends Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> s) {
            // Need to cast to raw in order to work around a limitation in the type system
            super((Set)s);
        }

        static <K, V> Consumer<Entry<K, V>> entryConsumer(Consumer<? super Entry<K, V>> action) {
            return e -> action.accept(new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.UnmodifiableEntry<>(e));
        }

        public void forEach(Consumer<? super Entry<K, V>> action) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(action);
            c.forEach(entryConsumer(action));
        }

        static final class UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator<K, V>
                implements Spliterator<Entry<K,V>> {
            final Spliterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> s;

            UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator(Spliterator<Entry<K, V>> s) {
                this.s = s;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Entry<K, V>> action) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(action);
                return s.tryAdvance(entryConsumer(action));
            }

            @Override
            public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Entry<K, V>> action) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(action);
                s.forEachRemaining(entryConsumer(action));
            }

            @Override
            public Spliterator<Entry<K, V>> trySplit() {
                Spliterator<Entry<K, V>> split = s.trySplit();
                return split == null
                        ? null
                        : new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator<>(split);
            }

            @Override
            public long estimateSize() {
                return s.estimateSize();
            }

            @Override
            public long getExactSizeIfKnown() {
                return s.getExactSizeIfKnown();
            }

            @Override
            public int characteristics() {
                return s.characteristics();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasCharacteristics(int characteristics) {
                return s.hasCharacteristics(characteristics);
            }

            @Override
            public Comparator<? super Entry<K, V>> getComparator() {
                return s.getComparator();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Spliterator<Entry<K,V>> spliterator() {
            return new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator<>(
                    (Spliterator<Map.Entry<K, V>>) c.spliterator());
        }

        @Override
        public Stream<Entry<K,V>> stream() {
            return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
        }

        @Override
        public Stream<Entry<K,V>> parallelStream() {
            return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), true);
        }

        public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
                private final Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> i = c.iterator();

                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return i.hasNext();
                }
                public Map.Entry<K,V> next() {
                    return new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.UnmodifiableEntry<>(i.next());
                }
                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Object[] toArray() {
            Object[] a = c.toArray();
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                a[i] = new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.UnmodifiableEntry<>((Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>)a[i]);
            return a;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
            // We don't pass a to c.toArray, to avoid window of
            // vulnerability wherein an unscrupulous multithreaded client
            // could get his hands on raw (unwrapped) Entries from c.
            Object[] arr = c.toArray(a.length==0 ? a : Arrays.copyOf(a, 0));

            for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
                arr[i] = new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.UnmodifiableEntry<>((Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>)arr[i]);

            if (arr.length > a.length)
                return (T[])arr;

            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, a, 0, arr.length);
            if (a.length > arr.length)
                a[arr.length] = null;
            return a;
        }

        /**
         * This method is overridden to protect the backing set against
         * an object with a nefarious equals function that senses
         * that the equality-candidate is Map.Entry and calls its
         * setValue method.
         */
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
                return false;
            return c.contains(
                    new UnmodifiableKeySetMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.UnmodifiableEntry<>((Map.Entry<?,?>) o));
        }

        /**
         * The next two methods are overridden to protect against
         * an unscrupulous List whose contains(Object o) method senses
         * when o is a Map.Entry, and calls o.setValue.
         */
        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
            for (Object e : coll) {
                if (!contains(e)) // Invokes safe contains() above
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == this)
                return true;

            if (!(o instanceof Set))
                return false;
            Set<?> s = (Set<?>) o;
            if (s.size() != c.size())
                return false;
            return containsAll(s); // Invokes safe containsAll() above
        }

        /**
         * This "wrapper class" serves two purposes: it prevents
         * the client from modifying the backing Map, by short-circuiting
         * the setValue method, and it protects the backing Map against
         * an ill-behaved Map.Entry that attempts to modify another
         * Map Entry when asked to perform an equality check.
         */
        private static class UnmodifiableEntry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
            private Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e;

            UnmodifiableEntry(Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e)
            {this.e = Objects.requireNonNull(e);}

            public K getKey()        {return e.getKey();}
            public V getValue()      {return e.getValue();}
            public V setValue(V value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
            public int hashCode()    {return e.hashCode();}
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o)
                    return true;
                if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
                    return false;
                Map.Entry<?,?> t = (Map.Entry<?,?>)o;
                return eq(e.getKey(),   t.getKey()) &&
                        eq(e.getValue(), t.getValue());
            }
            public String toString() {return e.toString();}
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the specified arguments are equal, or both null.
     *
     * NB: Do not replace with Object.equals until JDK-8015417 is resolved.
     */
    static boolean eq(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be in a standard library. I'm shocked that it isn't! It's a pretty regular use case. You create a map with a fixed set of keys but you only want to change the values after creation. Forcing users to use this type makes code safer. Thanks for posting it :)

Answer (score 6):

Use an enum as the key. Then one needn't care if they can add a new key since the key domain is fixed and finite. In fact, that's such a standard use case that Java provides `java.util.EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>,V>`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html

Comment: Actually, thats a great solution! But not for my particular problem, since I generate the key set at runtime...

Comment: FYI: This means you have a define set of keys at compile time. Didn't knew the implementation.

Comment: If you know the keys at compile time you might as well just use a class with public members.

Comment: @bhspencer I believe that is what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**1) The proxy**

I would reduce the scope of your `SemiMutableMap` to something like

```
interface ISemiMutableMap<U, V> {

    V get(U key);
    V set(U key, V value) throws Exception; //create your own maybe ?
}
```

This will reduce the possibilities of access but give you the full control of it.

And then implements it simply like a proxy

```
public class SemiMutableMap<U, V> implements ISemiMutableMap<U,V>{

    private Map<U, V> map;

    public SemiMutableMap(Map<U, V> map){ //get the predefine maps
        this.map = map;
    }

    public V get(U key){
        return map.get(U);
    }

    public V set(U key, V value) throws Exception{
        if(!map.containsKey(key)){
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return map.put(key,value);
    }
}
```

And you can add the methods you like to it off course.

**Note that this is not complety true, The constructor should clone the map instead of using the same reference but I am a bit lazy ;) and I've writen this without an IDE**

**2) The implementation**

Nothing prevent you to simply get the code of the `UnmodifiableMap` from the `Collections` and adapt it to your needs. From this, you will see it is quite simple to create your own implementation to your need.

Trust me, this class as been tested and reviewed ;)

You will need to adapt `put` to be able to update an existing value (same code as above) and `UnmodifiableEntry.setValue` to accept an update from the entry set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, but - I need a complete implementation of the `Map` interface, including an `Iterable` `EntrySet`, `containsXXX()` methods and other features exposed by the original `Map`.

Comment: @Elist Like I said in the second part, take the code from `Collections` and simply update the method `put` and `Entry.setValue`, you will have an `unmodifiableMap` that accept to update your values

Comment: @Elist I checked the logic, it is quite simple to understand but a bit long to add it here ;) but I only notice those two methods to update

Comment: Thanks - proxy works for me. Just coded this up and made some minor changes, which I'll add for future users:
-Change variable "m" to "map"
-Change return type of set to V in both interface & implementation

Comment: @ColmBhandal For typos, you can correct my answer if you want. If you have major improvements, it is better to post your answer. PS: I would suggest to return an `Optional<V>` if you can. This is better than return `null` for new key. But those are implementation choice, the design was what I was aiming ther ;)

Comment: @AxelH- snap! I just started using Optionals this week. Brings back the Haskell days. Since posting that I actually stopped using the class- total immutability was fine for me as long as I made my VALUE object mutable and my KEY ojbects immutable. I'll post a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't strictly what was asked in the question, but I think this approach is worth considering.

Use Google Guava's ImmutableMap and make your value type mutable- with a wrapper type if necessary.

Before moving on, it's important to understand this: immutability at the map level *only* means you can't re-assign objects. There's nothing stopping you from calling mutator methods on the objects already in the map. With this insight, the above approach might be obvious, but let me explain via an example.

For me, the value type was AmtomicInteger- already perfectly mutable in exactly the right way I needed, so I didn't need to change anything. However, in general, let's say you have a type T, and you want a partially mutable map for this type. Well, you can almost do this via a mutable map whose values are wrapper types for that class. Here's a really basic wrapper type, which you might want to enhance with some encapsulation:

```
public class Wrapper<T>{
  public T value;
  Wrapper(T t){value = t;}
}
```

Then you simply create a regular ImmutableMap in the normal way, except fill it with objects of Wrapper instead of objects of T. When using the values, you need to unbox them from the wrapper.

Again, I know this isn't what was asked, and unboxing from a wrapper might be too painful for some use cases, but I'd imagine this would work in a lot of cases. Certainly for me, it helped me realise that I already had a mutable type that was basically a wrapper for an int, and so the ImmmutableMap was fine.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to do something like this.

```
public class UnmodifiableKeyMap{

static enum MYKeySet {KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY4};
private Map myUnmodifiableHashMap = new HashMap();

public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return this.containsKey(key);
}


public Object get(Object key) {

    if(this.containsKey(key)){
        return this.myUnmodifiableHashMap.get(key);
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}

public Object put(Object key, Object value) throws Exception {

    if(this.containsKey(key)){
        this.myUnmodifiableHashMap.put(key, value);
    }

    throw new Exception("UnsupportedOperationException");
}


public Set keySet() {

    Set mySet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(MYKeySet.values()));
    return mySet;
}

public Collection values() {

    return this.myUnmodifiableHashMap.values();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry.. by the time I posted my answer you had already given the solution hence, no improvement.

Comment: Don't​ use raw types.

Comment: I think put method implementation is wrong it will execute always and throw exception