# Returning a new instance of HashMap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have a HashMap that stores a custom Object and maps it to a certain ArrayList in a class. My class communicates with another class (think MVC style) and it passes a copy of that hashmap. So, in my "model", I would have:

```
public Map<AbstractArtistry, ArrayList<AbstractCommand>> getHashMap() {
    return new LinkedHashMap<AbstractArtistry, ArrayList<AbstractCommand>>(this.hashmap);
  }
```

However, my "controller", when it gets that, can still edit the AbstractArtistries inside of the model's this.hashmap. To avoid this, do I have to create a new instance of an Abstract Artistry over and over, or is there a cleaner way to do this? Meaning, would I have to loop over model.hashmap.keySet(), create a new instance of every artistry, insert it into a new hashmap (and do the same for all the values), and then return that new hashmap? Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Are you saying your map's key type is mutable? That's asking for trouble...

Comment: @shmosel Too late to change the design now, but just for educational purposes, why?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to copy the lists? What about `AbstractCommand`?

Comment: Yeah, I would.. Damn, you are right, this design was bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streams to copy the map and replace the keys with defensive copies:

```
this.hashmap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> createCopy(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue))
```

If you need to copy the values as well, you can run them through a similar function:

```
ArrayList<AbstractCommand> copyList(ArrayList<AbstractCommand> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(c -> copyCommand(c))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

Comment: How do they all fit together so I could return a new hashmap?

Comment: @JohnLexus All of what? That snippet returns a map.

Comment: I am saying how do I combine the first and second snippets? The first snippet looks like it return a map with just keys and no values, while the second return a (map?) of the values, not with my AbstractArtistries as keys. Or am I reading this wrong (sorry new to Java)?

Comment: It's a hard to give you a functional snippet with the little detail you've provided. But basically you'd replace `Map.Entry::getValue` with `e -> copyList(e.getValue())` to copy the values.

Comment: I've updated the second snippet to return `ArrayList`. But ideally you should be sticking to the `List` interface.

Comment: I would have to make the "createCopy" method, right? Also, once I execute the first snippet, what does it return a new hashmap without editing the `this.hashmap` variable? So I could literally do `return (first snippet)`?

Comment: That's right. You would also have to create `copyCommand()`. Unless you don't need a deep copy, in which case you can just return `new ArrayList<>(list)`.

Comment: Hey man, do you know how I can make this return a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap?

Comment: You'll need to use the [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) overload that accepts a map supplier.

Comment: think you can provide an example...?