# What is the use of cloneable interface in java?

Tags: java, clone

What is the use of implementing a cloneable interface as it is a marker interface?

I can always make a public Object clone() method in my class. What is the actual purpose of cloneable interface?

Answer (score 7):

That's because the `clone()` method throws `CloneNotSupportedException` if your object is not `Cloneable`.

You should take a look at the [documentation for `clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method.

Following is how `clone()` method is declared in the class `Object`:

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
```

Note:

Also, it's been realized that `Clone` is broken. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326801/738746) here in SO explains why and how you can avoid using it.

Answer (score 4):

Making `Cloneable` a marker interface was a mistake.

That said, the one thing it does is "enable" the default implementation of `clone()` in `Object`. If you don't `implement Cloneable` then invoking `super.clone()` will throw a `CloneNotSupportedException`.

Comment: Could you explain why it was a mistake?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The Cloneable interface should have a clone method, and the protected clone method in Object shouldn't require "activation". The interface as it stands serves no real useful purpose, while using up a good name and causing confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Some people say it's an attempt to mimic copy constructor from C++, but here's the previous similar question on StackOverflow about it: [About Java cloneable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose is specified in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).  It is to specify that cloning of an object of this type is allowed.

If your class relies on the built-in implementation of `clone()` (provided by the `Object.clone()` method), then this marker interface *enables* field-by-field cloning.  (If you call the built-in clone method on an object that doesn't implement `Cloneable`, you get a `CloneNotSupportedException`.)

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of clone() method is create a new instance (copy) of object on which it is called. As you can see in answers for use clone method your class should implements the Cloneable interface. You can choose how implement clone , you can do shallow or deep copy for your class. You can see examples http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-clone-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy/.