# Why shouldn't an object be cloneable?

Tags: java, interface, clone, cloneable

I read lots of threads about the clone() method of Object and the Cloneable Interface but I couldn't find a legitimate answer to my question. 
Long story short:

What I figured out is that Object has a method clone() which can "magically" clone your object. But you can't use that method without implementing Cloneable Interface because this interface allows Object to use the clone() method. So why did they do that? Why shouldn't every object be cloneable from the start?

Comment: Open questions like `Why is foo implemented in this way?`, without a clear answer, are not a good fit for StackOverflow. See the [FAQ].

Comment: Have you done your [*homework*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloneable makes sense for some mutable data.

It doesn't make sense for

- immutable data
- where you might need a shallow or a deep copy.
- objects which represent resources such as threads, sockets, GUI components
- singleton and enumerated types
- mutable state where data should only be copied to avoid creating new objects.

Some coding styles suggest keeping new mutable data object to a minimum. Cloneable doesn't suit all situations and if you made all objects Cloneable you wouldn't be able to turn it off cleanly.

Note: There are many projects which avoid using Cloneable anywhere.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying that `clone` on an immutable object may simply return the same object.  The only fundamental problem (but it's a big one) with cloning occurs if an object encapsulates both the mutable state of some object or entity and also encapsulates the identity of that object.  When cloning a single object, it's possible for the clone to encapsulate either a detached copy of the original's state, or maintain the identity of the object used to encapsulate the original state, but not both.

Comment: If there were a convention that immutable types should implement `clone` as simply `return this`, then it would make sense to have separate types for collections of values (the values should implement `cloneable`) and collection-of-references (references' clone methods wouldn't be used).  To really make that work, there should have been a `cloneableObject` with a protected "magic" `memberwiseClone` method that would always work, as opposed to having a `clone` method in object that may or may not work; support for a public clone method would be independent of derivation from `cloneableObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Because if every object ( including the object of user-defined class) can be cloned just by using `clone` method then it might lead to the unintentional mutation of the original object being cloned as [`clone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) provides **shallow copy** of the original object. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
  private int val;
  public void setVal(int i)
  {
    this.val = i;
  }
  public int getVal()
  {
    return this.val;
  }
  public static void main(String st[]) throws Exception
  {
    ArrayList<MyClass> ar = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.setVal(50);
    ar.add(mc);
    ArrayList<MyClass> copy =(ArrayList) ar.clone();//Since ArrayList is cloneable
    copy.get(0).setVal(10);
    System.out.print(ar.get(0).getVal());//it shows 10 instead of 50!!
  }
}
```

Hence we see that Cloning may lead to inconsistency in the internal state of original object being copied. So to avoid such scenario , the prevalence is given to the programmer while defining the class whether he/she wants the object of that class to be cloned or not.

Comment: thank you for the vivid example :)

Answer (score -2):

Clone means to create the new copy of the object and doesn't share the memory location as happened in case of assignment operator.

Example

```
         MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();
         obj2 = obj1;
```

Here, in this case any changes you make to obj1 will reflect in obj2 and vice versa because obj2 holds the memory location of obj1.

but if you don't want, the change made in obj2 to be seen in obj1, or any change made in obj1 to be seen in obj2, then you perform Cloning. In this case both objects will have different memory location.