# Copy a Long object in Java

Tags: java

I think it should be:

```
Long a = Long.valueOf(0);
Long b = Long.valueOf(1);
Long a = b.clone();
```

But there is no `clone` method in `Long` object...

Maybe `Long a = Long.valueOf(b.LongValue())` will work, but it looks dirty. Is there any nice way to handle this?

Comment: `Long a = Long.valueOf(b.LongValue())` is correct

Comment: Another one: Long myLong = new Long(otherLong);

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Long's immutable, so wanting a cloned instance is a smell for there being an issue elsewhere.

Comment: Long is immutable.  There is no reason to create a copy of one.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I don't know why immutable and clone-able is conflict... could you give me any explanation?

Comment: Immutable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable

Comment: Cloneable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315628/why-shouldnt-an-object-be-cloneable

Comment: @Sayakiss It's not really a conflict as much as it doesn't buy you anything, and needing it is a sign you're doing something wrong. I used it once to quickly fix some code (`synchronized (myLong) { }` is a really bad idea). I could also see someone doing `IdentityHashMap<Long, Object>`, but using cloned longs there is a horrible abuse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think, *because* Long is immutable, you can just use an assignment.

```
Long a = (long) 1;
Long b = a;
a = (long) 2;
System.out.printf("a=%d, b=%d%n", a, b);
```

Output is

```
a=2, b=1
```

Comment: +1. Unless we get a convincing explanation for why a fresh instance is needed, simple assignment seems best.

Answer (score 7):

Something that looks much cleaner in my opinion:

```
Long a = b.LongValue()
```

There will be an implicit casting to the boxed value. The `b.LongValue()` will return the primitive long and it will automatically be boxed into an object of type `Long`.

You can read about boxing and auto-boxing [in this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for more information.

Here's the section that talks about autoboxing of primitives:

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.
>
> Here is the simplest example of autoboxing:
>
> Character ch = 'a';

Just for the completeness of the question:

- **Boxing** - The process of taking a primitive and use it in it's wrapper class. Meaning boxing `long` in `Long` or `int` in `Integer`, etc... You can get a boxed value either by creating a new object of the wrapper class as follows:

  ```
  Long boxed = new Long(1);
  ```

  Or by assigning a primitive to a variable of type of a wrapper class (**auto-boxing**):

  ```
  Long boxed = 1l;
  ```
- **Unboxing** - The opposite process of boxing. That's the process of taking a boxed parameter and get its primitive. Either by `getValue()` or by **auto-unboxing** as follows:

  ```
  Long boxed = new Long(1);
  long unboxed = boxed.getValue();
  ```

  Or by just assigning a boxed object to a primitive:

  ```
  long unboxed = new Long(1);
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in many ways :

```
Long a = b.LongValue(); // Autoboxing
```

OR

```
Long a = new Long(b);
```