# Deep copy "Object" type

Tags: java, deep-copy

I have an object with a member of type "Object":

```
class MyObject{
    Object member;

    public Object getObject(){
        return member;
     }

     public void setObject(Object obj){
         member = obj;
     }
}
```

Is it possible to deep copy `MyObject`?

Comment: You cannot guarantee deep copy here since Object could be anything. For example, a serialization technique here would fail if not all of the Object members implement Serializable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In its current implementation it is impossible because `member` can be anything and you cannot make a copy of what you dont know.

Comment: +1 There is no way to guarantee that an object is copyable at all, deep or shallow, until runtime when its only guaranteed interface is Object.

Comment: I think it's possible by using `reflection`.

Comment: @RongNK You can copy some objects using reflection (with fairly horrible performance), but not all. Database/network connections and open files come to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Implement `Cloneable` marker interface and you can copy of `MyObject` by clonning.

```
class MyObject implements Cloneable {
    public Object clone(){
      try {
        return super.clone();
      } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
           return null; 
      }
   }
}
```

Members also need to be `Cloneable` other wise it will throw `CloneNotSupportedException`.
...

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
MyObject obj1 = obj.clone();
```

Comment: That is `Cloneable` ;)

Comment: +1 too quick and sharp :)

Comment: What if `member` is not `Cloneable`?

Comment: Um... does clone() really deep copy, I thought it unless overridden just made a field by field copy...?

Comment: @BheshGurung member need to be also clonnable

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4081895/697449

Comment: Implementing Cloneable doesn't help, if I set new member-object of  obj, member of obj1 will be changed as well.

Comment: @yuris Yes, it does not deep copy, just shallow copy.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, yes, I asked how to make a deep copy.

Comment: @yuris Then this answer is not your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a bean, therefore not immutable, I have an alternative: the [freeze/thaw pattern](https://github.com/fge/btf/wiki/The-freeze-thaw-pattern).

If you implement it for your object (which would require that you use a builder class) you could then do:

```
final MyObject copy = orig.thaw().freeze();
```

I find it much more convenient than `Cloneable` or even builders (this is a reversible builder) and use that pattern a lot.

As a bonus, you could make your object NOT being a bean and therefore being immutable. I have a personal profound dislike of beans which is why I came up with that...

And this pattern is recursive too. Let us suppose that you have classes `Out` and `In` where `In` is a member of `Out`. Let us say that `In` obeys freeze/thaw. Your code for `Out` then becomes:

```
public final class Out
    implements Frozen<Builder>
{
    private final In in;

    private Out(final Builder builder)
    {
        in = builder.in.freeze();
    }

    public static newBuilder()
    {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public In getIn()
    {
        return in;
    }

    @Override
    public Builder thaw()
    {
        return new Builder(this);
    }

    public static final class Builder
        implements Thawed<Out>
    {
        private In.Builder in;

        private Builder()
        {
        }

        private Builder(final Out out)
        {
            in = out.in.thaw();
        }

        public Builder setIn(final In in)
        {
            this.in = in.thaw();
        }

        @Override
        public Out freeze()
        {
            return new Out(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The net result is that calling `copy = orig.thaw().frezze()` returns an *identical copy* with a *new* instance of `in`.