# Java equivalent of C++ copy assignment operator

Tags: java, c++, operator-keyword

I'm trying to understand this operator function written in C++ and convert it to Java.

```
Class& Class::operator=(const Class& In) {

   properties = In.properties;

   return *this;

}
```

Does this simply copy instance and properties of a class object? For which I've already written something:

```
public static Class copy(Class obj) {
    //returns new instance of Class individual
    Class copy =  new Class(obj.row_num, obj.col_num, obj.input_length, obj.output_length, obj.max_arity, obj.function_length, obj.levels_back);
    copy.genes = obj.genes.clone();
    return copy;
}
```

Am I on the correct track? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ampersand `&` designates a reference in C++. It is needed to provide the behavior similar to what Java objects provide "out of the box", because Java manages objects through references.

There is no copying going on in C++ when a reference is passed. In fact, avoiding copying is a major reason for using `const` references as function parameters.

The code that you show does not perform copying either: it changes its state based on the value being "assigned". The closest way of modeling this in Java would be providing an `assign(Class other)` method that changes the current state to match that of the object passed in:

```
Class assign(Class other) {
    this.properties = other.properties;
    return this;
}
```

You will need to use this method in place of C++'s assignment, like this:

```
Class clOne(args1);
Class clTwo(args2);
clOne = clTwo;      // Using the assignment operator
```

becomes this:

```
Class clOne = new Class(args1);
Class clTwo = new Class(args2);
clOne.assign(clTwo); // Using the assignment method instead of the operator
```

Answer (score 2):

> Am I on the correct track?

Kind of. But not quite. C++ distinguishes between reassigning an existing object and creating a new one.

Java doesn’t. You cannot reassign to an existing object in Java<sup>1</sup> (but you *can* of course reassign a reference). In Java, in order to *copy* an object (rather than assign a reference to it), you would usually use a copying constructor:

```
Class(Class other) {
    // Copy members of `other` into `this`.
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
Class x = new Class(something here);
Class y = new Class(x); // copy
```

In particular, this is what all the Java containers implement. I would *not* rely on `clone`. First of all, [`clone` should only be used if the class implements the tag interface `Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html). Second of all, [`clone`’s design is arguably broken](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/10/cloneable-interface-is-broken-in-java/) and [its use is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081895/1968).

---

<sup>1</sup> Well you *could* of course reassign the members of an object (unless they are `final`), and you could mimic C++’s copy assignment operator by providing a method `assign` to do that. However, this isn’t the conventional way of doing things in Java (although it might have its place in some exceptional instances).

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much on the right track. The copy assignment operator in C++ is used when directly assigning (copying) from one object to another. As Java objects are only accessible via references, such assignments are meaningless. To match the C++ semantics exactly, the Java equivalent would be:

```
public Class copy(Class obj) {
    row_num = obj.row_num;
    col_num = obj.col_num;
    // etc., etc.
    genes = obj.genes.clone();
    return this;
}
```