# How to Copy Everything Using Serializable in Java

Tags: java, constructor, parameter-passing, copy-constructor

I have lots of classes and circular references among them (e.g. an in class `A`, I have a set of objects from class `B` and class `B` has an attribute as an object of class `A` etc.)

When I try to copy everything from an object to another and modify the base object, because of the lists, I lose information.

Is there a way to copy every single bit from an object to another?

**Edit:**

Consider the following classes

```
class Book
{
    private Set<Page> pages;
    String title;
}

class Page
{
    private Set<String> lines;
    private int number;
    private int numberOfLines;
    private Book book;
}
```

should I use `Cloneable` for both or using just for `Book` is sufficient?

Could you please help me to write a copy constructor (or a method to copy) for `Book` class?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to do it yourself using recursion. Implement clone() in both, and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your object graph contains only `Serializable` classes, a common way to do a deep clone is to serialize the initial object and deserialize the result.

You can do this using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` classes.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without writing the object to a file?

Comment: Yes, you can write to an in memory byte array. See ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard out of the box mechanism. The usual way is to implement interface `Cloneable` or use apache commons utilities - have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable), or even simply create your own copy constructor manually.

Comment: clone() is directly on Object, no need to double-implement the interface. just override it.

Comment: @MightyPork `Object.clone()` - which you need to call to do a shallow field-wise clone - will throw if you don't implement `Cloneable`.

Comment: you sure @millimoose? If it's overriden, how can Object intercept the method access?

Comment: @MightyPork It doesn't intercept anything, but implementations of `clone()` can call `super.clone()` to not have to do the low-level cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a "copy constructor" as you said? It might be more verbose but it's explicit:

```
class A{
  public A(A other){ 
    bs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(B b : other.bs) bs.add(new B(b));
    /* copy other members */
  }
  private List<B> bs;
}

class B{
  public B(B other){ /* copy all members */ }
}
```

The advantage is that the intent is explicit. The disadvantage is a lot of boiler plate. As per the alternatives, cloning is not recommended, and serialization incurs quite a performance penalty.

This is a long shot, but you could consider using a tool like [ANTLR4](http://www.antlr.org/) to write a tool to generate the "copy constructors" for you.