# Clone an derived class

Tags: java, clone

I'm trying to implement the clone of a derived class, but , I didn't get, I don't know why.
Why can't I clone the class B?, I get an CastClassExpcetion.

```
public class A implements Cloneable {
    private Integer a;

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        A clone = new A(); //Why if I do this instance of super.clone() I get an exception?
        A clone = (A) super.clone();
        clone.a = this.a;
        return clone;
    }
      ..

}

public class B extends A implements Cloneable {
    private String b;
..
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        B clone = (B) super.clone();
        clone.b = this.b;
        return clone;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        B b = new B(1, "s");
        B clone = b.clone();                
    }

}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable

Comment: By seeing your code (in special your clone implementation and your main-method), i do think that you dont know what you are doing.
What do you want to archieve? Why `System.out.println("A");`?

Comment: Well, it was just for knowing the code had ended.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistakenly returning `a` and `b` in your `clone()` methods. This causes an exception in `B.clone()`, since you can't cast an integer to a `B`.

To fix, just ensure you return your `clone` variable instead.

---

Also note that fields values are automatically copied to your clone object. There is no need to assign field values to your clone, unless they are mutable and you wish to defensively copy them. In your clone methods, you have these redundant lines:

```
clone.a = this.a;
```

and

```
clone.b = this.b;
```

You can remove both lines from your `B.clone()`  method, since strings and integers are immutable.

Comment: When I do A clone = (A) super.clone();, Shouldn't I do A clone = new A(); and then I get an CastClassException? Because if I do super.clone(), am I not working with the same reference? and that's not a clone. Or it looks like when I debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a ClassCastException, because A != B
By calling **super.clone()** (in object B), you will get a object of A. (because **super** is **A**)
But object of A cannot be casted to B!
 
(A is not child of B, but B is child of A)

I other simplier words:
B is/contains **more** than A (it **extends** A!)
So, you cannot **cast** A to B, because **A is missing the B part**! (and this is needed to have an object of B!)
On the other side, you can cast B to A, because **B contains A**.

```
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

    B clone = (B) super.clone(); //here is the problem! A is not (cannot be casted to) B.
    clone.b = this.b;
    return clone;
}
```

You cannot cast Car to Porsche (it is **more** than just a car), but you can cast Porsche to Car.