# example of a class that implements Cloneable Java

Tags: java, cloneable

From what I have read about the `Cloneable` interface its a waste of time but we still have to study it for some reason. I have been going through sample questions but can not find an answer to the one below.

Example of a class that implements clonable?

Anyone have an example of a class that implements cloneable?

---edit---

This question is not a duplicate as this question clearly states that I'm looking for an "Example of a class that implements cloneable?"

The question that ye state it is a duplicate of(stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-clone‌​able) does not ask for an example and I had read it and all other cloneable related questions long before posting this question.

Comment: There are a lot classes in the jre: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Cloneable.html

Comment: @AndrewTobilko in the op question he does not mention anything about an example of a class that implements Cloneable

Comment: @Jens: Oh sweet, I didn't know that tab existed.

Comment: how is this question a duplicate when there are no other questions here asking for classes that implements clonable? the link that Andrew Tobilko post and since deleted had no mention of a cloneable example(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable). i read it long before i posted.

Comment: In the future, reference the similar questipns you've read that didnt answer your question and explain why when asking your question. Not in a passive aggressive manner after the fact.

Comment: @TinyGiant thanks for the advice. i apologize for the passive aggressive manner of my response but i was banned for a few months because of this question and was never told why. Now i know and will do so in future.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Java Collections Framework classes implement it, so classes like `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, and `HashMap`.

As Jens points out in the comments, there's a "Use" link at the bottom of the Javadoc that takes you to a [page full of uses of the `Cloneable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Cloneable.html):

[image]

If you scroll down on that page, you'll see long lists of classes in various packages that implement `Cloneable`.

Comment: The “Use” link is also at the top of each page.