# Verifying a member variable implements clone() method

Tags: java, object

I'm Trying to create a copy of the data Object passed as argument and assigning it to the data member variable in the following class (Includes what I've tried so far)

```
public abstract class AbstractVertex implements Vertex {
private String label;
private Object data;

public AbstractVertex(String label, Object data) {
    this.label = label;

    //What I've tried so far :
    //Method #1
    if(!(data instanceof Cloneable)){
        throw new RuntimeException("data's class doesn't implement a custom clone method");
    }
    this.data = data.clone();

    //Method #2 (Just to get the idea behind this method, syntax may be completely wrong)
    if(( data.getClass().getMethod(clone()) ) == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("data's class doesn't implement a custom clone method");
    }
  }
}
```

So my problem is that I can't implement any of these methods because the `clone()` method in the `Object` class is protected. But since I need to be able to store any type of data in the class `AbstractVertex` , I absolutely have to make sure the stored `data` is actually a copy of the one passed in parameter and not passed by reference.

So, how do I tackle this problem?

N.B: This is the abstract class, inheriting class will use this constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your method 2 is wrong, not just syntax but logic. In java every class is a subclass of `Object` and since `Object` has a protected `clone()` method, whether they implement `Cloneable` or not every class has a protected `clone()` method. So `someObject.getClassc().getMethod("clone")` never returns `null`.

As for your method 1, since **clone()** method is protected you need to call it using reflection like this;

```
    //Method #1
    if(!(data instanceof Cloneable)){
        throw new RuntimeException("data's class doesn't implement a custom clone method");
    }
    Method cloneMethod = data.getClass().getMethod("clone");
    this.data = cloneMethod.invoke(data);
```

Also i think you should take a look at this question: [About Java cloneable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable). Using deep-cloning and shallow-cloning like it is mentioned in the link is the practice you should implement.