# Cloning a List in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, deep-copy

I am working on a function in a object that takes in a List of objects as a parameter and clone its contents into its own List. Modifying the new List should not affect the List that was passed in. I know the List would be passed by reference, but would the objects within the list be passed by reference or value? (sorry if this sounds dumb)

I am passing in a list of pieces (pawn, rook etc.) that extends a Piece class. I was thinking of creating a clonePiece() function in the Piece class but I don't know how to go about doing it. This is what I have so far:

```
    public void copyPieces(List<Piece> whitePieces, List<Piece> blackPieces){
    for (int i = 0; i < whitePieces.size(); i++){
        this.whitePieces.add(whitePieces.get(i).clonePiece());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < blackPieces.size(); i++){
        this.whitePieces.add(blackPieces.get(i).clonePiece());
    }
```

How would you go about implementing a clonePiece() function in an abstract class that creates a new instance of its inherited classes?

edit:

```
public abstract class Piece {
private int color;
private int x;
private int y;

public Piece (int color, int x, int y){
    this.color = color;
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
}

public int getColor(){
    return this.color;
}
public int getX(){
    return this.x;
}
public int getY(){
    return this.y;
}

public void move(int x, int y, Board board){
    board.getGameTiles()[this.x][this.y].setToUnoccupied();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public abstract ArrayList<Move> getMoves(Board board);

public Piece clonePiece(){
    return this;
}
```

}

```
public class Rook extends Piece{

int x, y, color;
private ArrayList<Move> moves;

public Rook(int color, int x, int y) {
    super(color, x, y);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    moves = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Move> getMoves(Board board) {

    //moves right
    int a = 1;
    while(UtilFunctions.isInBoundaries(x+a, y)){
        if(!board.getGameTiles()[x+a][y].isTileOccupied()){
            //add move type 0 for passive move
            moves.add(new Move(x, y, x+a, y, 0));
        }
        else{
            if(board.getGameTiles()[x+a][y].getPiece().getColor() != this.color){
                //add move type 1 for attack move
                moves.add(new Move(x, y, x+a, y, 1));
            }
            break;
        }
        a++;
    }

    //moves left
    a = -1;
    while(UtilFunctions.isInBoundaries(x+a, y)){
        if(!board.getGameTiles()[x+a][y].isTileOccupied()){
            //add move type 0 for passive move
            moves.add(new Move(x, y, x+a, y, 0));
        }
        else{
            if(board.getGameTiles()[x+a][y].getPiece().getColor() != this.color){
                //add move type 1 for attack move
                moves.add(new Move(x, y, x+a, y, 1));
            }
            break;
        }
        a++;
    }

    //moves up
    a = 1;
    while(UtilFunctions.isInBoundaries(x, y+a)){
        if(!board.getGameTiles()[x][y+a].isTileOccupied()){
            //add move type 0 for passive move
            moves.add(new Move(x, y, x, y+a, 0));
        }
        else{
            if(board.getGameTiles()[x][y+a].getPiece().getColor() != this.color){
                //add move type 1 for attack move
                moves.add(new Move(x, y, x, y+a, 1));
            }
            break;
        }
        a++;
    }

    //moves down
    a = -1;
    while(UtilFunctions.isInBoundaries(x, y+a)){
        if(!board.getGameTiles()[x][y+a].isTileOccupied()){
            //add move type 0 for passive move
            moves.add(new Move(x, y, x, y+a, 0));
        }
        else{
            if(board.getGameTiles()[x][y+a].getPiece().getColor() != this.color){
                //add move type 1 for attack move
                moves.add(new Move(x, y, x, y+a, 1));
            }
            break;
        }
        a++;
    }

    return moves;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to clone the pieces themselves too? Are the immutable or do they contain some mutable state?

Comment: Yeah I would like to clone the pieces themselves and put them in the new list. Not sure about mutability (I am pretty new to programming), but the Pieces are just classes that extend the Piece class. (i.e knights, bishops)

Comment: Could you post the code of the `Piece` class and one of it's descendants too?

Answer (score 1):

Your children classes shouldn't have any fields extra than the parent class Piece. There is nothing inherently different at this level. Remove the other fields from the children classes and give then access to the parent Piece class fields.

```
abstract class Piece {

    Piece(boolean white, int x, int y){
        //set fields
        ...
    }

    public abstract Piece copyPiece();
}
```

Then implement the method copyPiece() in all children classes. Then call:

```
public void copyPieces(List<Piece> whitePieces, List<Piece> blackPieces){
    for (Piece whitePiece : whitePieces){
        this.whitePieces.add(whitePiece.copyPiece());
    }
    for (Piece blackPiece : blackPieces){
        this.blackPieces.add(blackPiece.copyPiece());
    }
}
```

Edit after posting code:

My original answer doesn't fit due to the code posted. Revised accordingly.

A few things seem odd to me. First, color could be a boolean, `white`, since there are only two colors. Next, it seems strange that your `Rook` class cannot have set access to the `x` and `y` fields of the parent `Piece` class.

Your `clonePiece` class does nothing but return itself, this is not a clone at all. A clone would be: `return new Piece(this.color, this.x, this.y);`

Next, your `move(x, y, board)` method isn't correct. First, consider not passing in the `board` and having the class that uses the move method be the one to manipulate it. If you do not want to go this route, you have to set the new position of the piece on the board, not just remove the old one.

Comment: This is not going to work because he's using inheritance.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to programming, but how would you copy the fields in its descendants in the Piece class? Lets say I want to copy a bishop which inherits from Piece. How does the line "new Piece(whitePiece)" access the data in bishop?

Comment: Your Rook class should not have any extra fields than a Piece does. There is nothing inherently different from a Rook to a Pawn at the field level. Remove all fields of the children classes.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. It seems like I have a very poor grasp of object-oriented programming. As for my previous question, I meant to ask how would the copy constructor know that the piece copied is a Bishop or a Rook? If I were to create a new Piece, will it know which descendant class to create?

Comment: The copy constructor wouldn't know what piece it is. It would return a type Piece. If there were extra fields in the children it wouldn't copy those extra fields.

Answer (score 1):

Have piece return its own `#copy` method (Or use `Clonable`):

```
public abstract class Piece {

    public Piece copy() {
        //return copy
    }
}
```

This can similarly be used in subclasses:

```
public class Rook extends Piece {

    @Override
    public Rook copy() {
        //return copy
    }
}
```

Then, when you have a list of `Piece` objects, you simply call `#copy` on the objects and replace the references in your list. For example:

```
List<Piece> pieces = /* some list */;
List<Piece> copy = new ArrayList<>(pieces);
copy.replaceAll(Piece::copy); //replace references with copies
```

Comment: What would be the code in copy() in the Piece class? Would it work if I made copy() abstract in the Piece class and override it in each of the inherited classes?

Comment: sure, that'd be reasonable. The idea is to simply have your `#copy`/`#clone` make a new proper instance for the individual subclasses. Making it abstract would enforce any implementing subclass to supply a copy. The added benefit is that each subclass can ensure things within it (e.g. a list) are copied appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Clonable` is [commonly recommended to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081982/7216176) and I would therefore advice you to instead implement a copy constructor or your own method for copying.

This is my suggested implementation:

In order to benefit from [polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm), add an abstract method for making [deep copies](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/deepCopying.htm) in `Piece`

```
public abstract Piece deepCopy();
```

and corresponding implementations in the subclasses

```
@Override
public Rook deepCopy() {
    Rook rook = new Rook(this.getColor(), this.getX(), this.getY());
    for (Move m : this.moves) {
        rock.addMove(new Move(m));
    }
    return rook;
}
```

`color`, `x` and `y` are all of primitive types which means that, at assignment, the value is copied. However, `Rook` also contains the field `move` which is a List of the reference type `Move`. This means that to be able to make a deep copy, also the `Move` class needs to contain a copy constructor or method for copying. The former is shown here.

```
public Move(Move move) {
    this(move.x, move.y);
}
```

Finally, copy your list of pieces either the Java 7 way:

```
List<Piece> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Piece p : oldList) {
    newList.add(p.deepCopy());
}
```

or the Java 8 way (as previously suggested by [Darshan Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833017/7216176)):

```
List<Piece> newList = whitePieces.stream()
    .map(p -> p.deepCopy())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Updated the example to support inheritance

You can make `Piece` class implement `Cloneable` interface and override clone method in the impl classes. Piece and Rook classes will look like this:

```
abstract class Piece implements Cloneable{
    int x;
    int y;

    protected void copy(Piece p){
        p.x = this.x;
        p.y = this.y;
    }
}

class Rook extends Piece{
    int z;

    @Override
    public Object clone(){
        Rook rook = new Rook();
        super.copy(rook);
        rook.z = this.z;
        return rook;
    }
}
```

Once this is done, you can call this method on any piece object and get the deep cloned instance. Below is Java 8 stream example that deep clones list of pieces:

```
List<Rook> pieces = new ArrayList<>();

List<Piece> cloned = pieces.stream()
                     .map(p -> (Piece) p.clone())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: @ToddSewell updated the answer to support inheritance

Comment: Would I implement a clone() function in every class that inherits from piece? If this is the case, would I be able to call .clone() on a Piece object? For example, if I want to clone a List<Piece> whitePieces, could I still call whitePieces.get(0).clone(), even when clone() is not defined in Piece?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement `clone()` method in all the classes as Piece class won't have knowledge of fields of child classes. And yes, calling `clone()` on `Piece` reference will actually call the impl class, depending on which `instance` is being referenced. That's how inheritance works..