# javascripts Object.assign equivalent in java with out mutating original object

Tags: javascript, java, java-8

I have a person object whose properties are initially null and through various stages object properties are populated, In javascript land I can have Object.assign which can create a new object without mutating the orignal object, Is there anything in java which can do the job for me. Key is immutability for me.

Comment: Please specify the reason for negative ratings?.

Comment: Have you tried cloning the object?

Comment: Try to add more details and code examples.  That makes the question much clearer and you will be more likely to get an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an immutable object in Java, read the documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

For the Javascript Object.assign functionality, you can implement the Cloneable interface, there is however some discussion about that, so you might want to use a third party library like BeanUtils or SerializationUtils, as described in this answer:

[About Java cloneable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable)