# How does implementing Cloneable interface allows cloning of objects, as it is a Marker Interface and doesn't have any methods?

Tags: java, clone, cloneable, marker-interfaces

I am having a class whose object I want to clone. I did that by implementing the Cloneable interface and overriding the clone method. But if I am creating a clone method, without implementing the Cloneable interface, it is throwing an exception.
What super power does this Marker Interface (Cloneable) is providing to my class?

Comment: The same way `Serializable` writes objects to disk, despite it being a marker interface.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081982/6395627) to the duplicate explains how implementing `Cloneable` works. The interface is simply telling the _native_ `Object.clone` method, "hey, you can clone me". Without the interface the method will refuse to clone the object (by throwing an exception). As mentioned by Elliot, this is similar to how `Serializable` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning of objects in java :

There is the `Cloneable` interface. You would expect the interface to have a clone() method, which would return a copy of the object. But, it is not the case. `Cloneable` is just a marker interface. That means, it has no methods whatsoever, it just marks the class as suitable for cloning. The `clone` method is present on the `Object` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

It allows cloning according to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) of `Object.clone`:

> First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface
>   `Cloneable`, then a `CloneNotSupportedException` is thrown.

Everytime you call `Object.clone()` this requirement is verfied.

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Cloneable.html) of `Cloneable` itself says:

> A class implements the `Cloneable` interface to indicate to the
>   `Object.clone()` method that it is legal for that method to make a
>   field-for-field copy of instances of that class. Invoking Object's
>   clone method on an instance that does not implement the `Cloneable`
>   interface results in the exception `CloneNotSupportedException` being
>   thrown.

Summarizing it:
It's part of the specified behavior. Not complying with this requirement will be obvoius at runtime.