# Why can't we achieve deep cloning through getters in java why we need prototype design pattern with Cloneable interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, cloneable

I need to know in a case of we need to clone an instance deeply why can't we achieve that using the getter method of our original object why we need any specific design pattern or interface like Cloneable ?

Comment: You should know that [`Cloneable` is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable)