# How to copy properties from a bean to another bean in different class?

Tags: java, javabeans

I have two java class with same properties names.How Can I copy all the properties to another bean filled with data.I don't want to use the traditional form to copy properties because I have a lot of properties.

Thanks in advance.

**1 class**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userSessionId;
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String adress;
    ......................
```

**2 class**

```
public class UserBean {

    private String userSessionId;
    private String userId;
    private String name;
   ....................
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5937567/193634

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use [`BeanUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils):

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

UserBean newObject = new UserBean(); 
BeanUtils.copyProperties(newObject, oldObject);
```

Comment: It is NOT BeanUtils.copyProperties(oldObject, newObject) but BeanUtils.copyProperties(newObject, oldObject)!

Comment: If you are using org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils then use like `BeanUtils.copyProperties(oldObject,newObject );`

Comment: Simple format :  BeanUtils.copyProperties(DomainBean, FormBean);

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Dozer Framework](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) - its an object to object mapping framework. The idea is that:

- Usually it will map by convention.
- You can override this convention with a mapping file.

. . therefore mapping files are as compact as possible. Its useful for many cases, such as mapping a use-case specify service payload on to the reusable core model objects.

When delivering the SpringSource training courses we used to point out this framework very often.

*Edit:*

These days try [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/).

Comment: Btw: I've voted to close this question as a duplicate, and expanded the existing Dozer answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5937567/193634

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache's library, BeanUtils, you can do this easily:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

In particular, look at copyProperties(Object, Object)

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)

> Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for
>   all cases where the property names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use java reflection to set and get property values.  There is spring bean property util which does the property value access. I would recommend to you java reflection.