# Converting a List of POJO into List of some other POJO in Java Stream

Tags: java

I have 2 POJO Foo and `FooDBObj`, I fetch List of `FooDBObj` from database and now I need to create List of `Foo` Objects. I need to set Id and name in `FooDBObj` into Foo's `BarId` and `BarName` respectively. If its in Java Stream it will be better

I have tried to get the list of Id's alone from below code.

```
List<String> fooIds =FooDBObjList.stream().map(FooDBObj::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code can give me only list of Id for Foo I need all the `FooDBObj.id` to be set in `Foo.BarId` and `FooDBObj.name` to be set in `FooDBObj.BarName`

Comment: I think that Link is usefull for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760590/how-to-copy-properties-from-a-bean-to-another-bean-in-different-class

Comment: Because `FooDBObj::getId` don't create a different instance but just extract the ID. Use a method to create a `Foo` instance from a `FooDBObj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could simply write the mapping logic directly:

```
Stream<Foo> = fooDBObjList.stream()
  .map(db -> {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setBarId(db.Id);
    foo.setBarName(db.name);

    return foo;
  });
```

If `Foo` already have an appropriate constructor (or a factory method like `Foo.from(FooDbObj)` it could be done via method reference:

```
Stream<Foo> = fooDbObjList.stream().map(Foo::from); // Factory method
….map(Foo::new) // if Foo(FooDbObj) constructor
….map(db -> new Foo(db.Id, db.name)) // if Foo(barId, barName) constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can go like this too,

```
fooDBObjList.stream().forEach(x -> {
            Foo foo = new Foo ();
            foo.setId(x.getid());
            foo.setName(x.getname());   
            foooList.add(foo);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fooDBObjList.stream()
    .map(Foo:map)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

in Foo class:

```
Foo map(FooDBObj dbObj) {
   return Foo.builder
              .id(dbObj.getId())
              .name(dbObj.getName())
              .build();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
One can use below snippet:


  List foo = FooDBObjList.stream().map(fooDBObj -> { Foo f = new Foo();
                                                          f.setBarName(fooDBObj.getName());
                                                          f.setBarId(fooDBObj.getId()); 
                                                          return f;}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```